# Vertical reveal effect like collapsing view in RecycleView cell

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to find a solution to recycle view like this: [image: https://s.yimg.com/cv/api/adspecs/formats/20180808/f4449_img1533737262.gif]

I've tried many ways but still have no success, maybe somebody could give me a hint for that or advise library?

Comment: So what did you try so far ?

Comment: 1. I was trying to add OnTouchListener and change height of view in cell - it is very hard to get smooth acting.    2. Now I'm trying to implement this library, but it is acting not as expected inside recycleview cell https://github.com/colorgreen/swipe-touch-listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I can't explain why but the solution in my case was to set paddings of content equal ***doubled*** distance to visible top of the table:

```
 @Override
 public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
  int contentPaddingTop =  -childView.getTop() * 2; 
  childView.setPadding(0,contentPaddingTop,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I almost solved the problem with setting padding in onScroll, but actually have no idea why content offset is different than getTop()?

```
 @Override
 public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
  int contentPaddingTop =  -childView.getTop(); 
  childView.setPadding(0,contentPaddingTop,0,0);
}
```

https://files.fm/f/vjwy46m7

Comment: What do mean buy `content offset`? What else you need to do?

Comment: Watch the video: I need the view in targeted cell to be stuck and do not move while scrolling list, but it is moving anyway.

Comment: I mean when cell first start to appear you must see the very bottom of the view (padding = view.height), but it is start appearing from the middle of view. Never the less when view fully on screen it works correctly (padding = 0).

Answer (score 0):

May be something is wrong with my layout for the cell?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:clipChildren="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_foxy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/fox700"
            />

  </RelativeLayout>
```